# VB - SQL Fatal internal connection error -Closed

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net

So every time i try to write to the Database, running on MySQL the program give out an error(Fatal internal connection error).

This is the code being used :

```
    Dim SQLcon As New SqlConnection("Server=127.0.0.1; Database=storedatabase; User Id=root; Password=root;")
Dim cmd As SqlCommand
```

---

```
Try
    SQLcon.Open()
    cmd.Connection = SQLcon
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Items (ItemName, ItemPrice, ItemQTY) VALUES ('" & Item & "','" & Price & "','" & Qty & "');"
    SQLcon.Close()
    MsgBox("Added " & Item & " to Database", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
```

---

VB gives this error :

```
An exception (first chance) of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll.
```

The SQL port is changed to 1433.

Database with tables exist.

EDIT :
After adding the Port=1433 to the connection string i get this error :

```
InnerExecption = {"Keyword not supported: 'port'."}
```

Connection String :

```
Dim SQLcon As New SqlConnection("Server=127.0.0.7; Port=1433; Database=storedatabase; User Id=root; Password=root;")
```

Comment: Can you post your modified connection string pls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bah, I'm an idiot.

You are trying to connect to a MySQL Database using MSSQL's client library.  You need to use the MySql Connector:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-net-programming-connecting-connection-string.html

```
Dim SQLcon As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection("Server=127.0.0.1; Port=1433; Database=storedatabase; User Id=root; Password=root;")
Dim cmd As SqlCommand
```

Comment: Its all internal no external connection so im not worried about SQLi,
ItemPrice and ItemQTY are Int in the DB and ItemName is String.
I will try your code.

Comment: Is there an inner exception in the thrown exception?

Comment: Faceplam... i need the mysql imports... well i guess then this answerd my question.- WORKED ... thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try, using `uid` for `UserID` and `pwd` for `Password`:

```
Dim SQLcon As New MySqlConnection("Server=127.0.0.1; Database=storedatabase; uid=root; pwd=root;")
```

See [link](http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql-connector-net-mysqlconnection/)

You need to use import at the Global Level of your class, like:

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
```

I am assuming by the way that you are using [MySQL connector](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/5.1.html) since it is not native in dotNet unlike Sql server. Otherwise the `Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient` namespace will not work.